# How to use dcast with dynamic number of columns in LHS in R

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am trying to build a excel like pivot table UI using Shiny wherein user can choose multiple fields as row headers and one field as column header.
I am using dcast to create a pivot table and display the final output in the Shiny app.
The issue I am facing is that how do I use dcast when I do not know how many columns the user is going to select (since multiple selection is allowed)?

Basically I want to have something like this:

dcast(data_table, Column1 + Column2 + ... + ColumnN ~ ColumnsX, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = ColumnZ)

where,
Column1, ... ,ColumnN , ColumnsX, ColumnZ are all user selected columns.
The list of selected columns is available in a vector of character string say:
input_list = c("Column1","Column2",...,"ColumnN")

I am also open to alternative solutions to this problem without using dcast.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using formula interface, it is handy to know that you can also provide it as a text string.

```
dt <- data.frame(y = c(1,2,3), x1 = c(1,2,3), x2 = c(1,2,3))
```

Sorry for the nonsense example, but it gets the point across.

Here's the simple form:

```
dcast(dt, y ~ x1 + x2)
```

Now we supply it in text form with `as.formula`:

```
dcast(dt, as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2"))
```

And here we go even further, making it completely dynamic based on variable naming:

```
dcast(dt, as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(grep("^x", colnames(dt), value = T), collapse = "+"))))
```

All three provide identical output.

And in your case of shiny app, you probably get the vector of names supplied by some selection method in the UI. So in this case, it would look like something along these lines:

```
server <- function(input, output){
    output$sometable <- renderTable({
        dcast(dt, as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(input$someselectionmethod, collapse = "+"))))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. While second option work for me, Can I further improve the 3rd option in case when my column names does not have a pattern?

Comment: Well, you have to get the list of names from somewhere. Either from some other object, or by pattern, or supplying it by external file.. or anything really.    It can't just guess a list of names, you have to provide the logic.